# How to play two videos side by side using FFmpeg?

Tags: shell, video, ffmpeg

Hello I want to create a duet video feature like tiktok. I am using FFmpeg. I have tried this code

```
ffmpeg \
  -i movie_output.mp4 \
  -i movie_output.mp4 \
  -filter_complex  \
    "nullsrc=size=360x480[base]; 
     [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x480, crop=180:480:90:0[left];
     [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x480, crop=180:480:90:0 [right];
     [base][left] overlay=x=0:y=0[base1];
     [base1][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=180:y=0" \
  -c:v libx264 \
  -y result.mp4
```

It gives me this error:

```
No such filter: ' '
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Whole output

```
ubuntu@ip-171-xx-xx-xxx: ffmpeg -i movie_output.mp4 -i movie_output.mp4 -filter_complex  "nullsrc=size=360x480[base]; \ [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x480, crop=180:480:90:0[left]; \ [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x480, crop=180:480:90:0 [right]; \ [base][left] overlay=x=0:y=0[base1]; \ [base1][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=180:y=0" -c:v libx264 -y result.mp4


ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'movie_output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    comment         : vid:v090440c0000brppph37mt2vmmsj1dig
  Duration: 00:00:08.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1135 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 540x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 996 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'movie_output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    comment         : vid:v090440c0000brppph37mt2vmmsj1dig
  Duration: 00:00:08.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1135 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 540x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 996 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x560fd395e2e0] No such filter: ' '
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

I have tried this as well

```
ffmpeg \
  -report \
  -i "movie_output.mp4" \
  -i "movie_output.mp4" \
  -an \
  -filter_complex \
     "[0:v]trim=start=0:end=9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[firstclip];
      [1:v]trim=start=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[secondclip];
      [0:v]trim=start=9:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeoutsrc];
      [1:v]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeinsrc];
      [fadeinsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadein];
      [fadeoutsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadeout];
      [fadein]fifo[fadeinfifo];
      [fadeout]fifo[fadeoutfifo];
      [fadeoutfifo][fadeinfifo]overlay[crossfade];
      [firstclip][crossfade][secondclip]concat=n=3" \
  outputname.mp4
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg started on 2020-06-27 at 10:11:41
Report written to "ffmpeg-20200627-101141.log"
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'movie_output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    comment         : vid:v090440c0000brppph37mt2vmmsj1dig
  Duration: 00:00:08.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1135 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 540x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 996 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'movie_output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    comment         : vid:v090440c0000brppph37mt2vmmsj1dig
  Duration: 00:00:08.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1135 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 540x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 996 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[NULL @ 0x562dea344220] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -filter_complex'
 -filter_complex: Invalid argument
```

This code gives this error

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -filter_complex'
     -filter_complex: Invalid argument
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/267698/how-do-i-use-ffmpegs-filter-complex

Comment: Each command begins with `-i "movie_output.mp4"` **twice**.  Remove the duplicate.